# cURL Error when using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: php, curl

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in /home/public_html/curl.php on line
```

Trying to use `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);` but I'm getting this error. How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your setup has either safe mode or open_basedir settings in the php.ini.

You need to change these settings in the php.ini to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

Comment: this one won't do the job. it's because of the server's setting. you should turn safe_mode and open_basedir off